# ALSA doesn't recognize sound card (ubuntu 22.04 )

Tags: sound

I was trying to get my audio to work simultaneously on my 2 different sound cards (Analog and HDMI) but during my attempts, I somehow lost all my audio devices (Input and output).
So, I tried a quite a few things when I reviewed Ubuntu stuff related to this type of problem in Stack Exchange.
So far I have done the following:
Uninstalled and reinstalled pulsaudio and pavucontrol and also the following:
sudo touch /usr/share/pipewire/media-session.d/with-pulseaudio
systemctl --user restart pipewire-session-manager

Installed a new kernel (5.19.0.26-generic to 5.19.1) thinking that would reinstall the drivers (which appear to be misssing)
and to be honest a few other suggested remedies that didn't work
However, I did collect all my sound information using
sudo wget -O alsa-info.sh http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh && chmod +x ./alsa-info.sh && ./alsa-info.sh
The data is located at http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=994e1c2832ac2ce3e7ea75e290f98ff9467c27ae
One thing did give me quite a bit of hope but didn't pan out. When I performed a
"sudo modprobe snd-hda-intel" the output devices actually showed up under my audio configuration (but not the input devices i.e microphones), however when I tried to test the speaker I got an error - "error trying to play test sound, the system said no such driver" but I do get sound out of them (e.g. youtube)??
One last bit off information, pulseaudio does not autostart on booting my system, I have to do it manually after the system boots (pulseaudio --start).
Additional Progress:
After manually doing "sudo modprobe snd_usb_audio" and "sudo modprobe snd-hda-intel" I have all my devices back but if I reboot, I have to manually restart pulseaudio, and the 2 modprobe command to get them back. The problem I see now is that these should load automatically and not manually. Not sure how to resolve that.

Any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Gave up and reinstalled Ubuntu 22.04. The machine was needed and that was the quickest way (if you call 6 hours quick) to get it back to a somewhat normal condition. What fun!